# Control bar wider than video in html5 + css

Tags: html, cross-browser, html5-video

I tried including the width and height attributes in html5 to manipulate the dimensions of the frame of my video but it doesn't seem to get bigger or smaller proportionally to the control bar. What I mean is that it seems to be that the control bar of the video( the one with the play/pause and volume controls) is a lot wider than the actual video frame which looks quite awkward, so I would like to know how I could make the control bar and video frame equally wide. I think a couple of screen shots will offer a little more clarity to the problem I am having.

[image: This is the display of the video in mozilla]

[image: This is the display of the video in chrome]

My apologies for the messy code but I have included it if that helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html style="height:100%; width=1200px;margin:0;padding:0;">

<body style="height:100%;width=100%;margin:0;padding:0;">
<div id="container" style="background-color:#FFA500;height:100%;width:100%;position:relative;min-height:800px;min-width:1000px;" >

    <div id="logo_login_pass" style="border:1px solid black; height:25%;width:94%;background-color:white;position:relative;float:right;min-height:150px;min-width:700px;">
        <div id="logo" style="border:1px solid black; height:80%; width:30%; background-color:green; position:absolute;bottom:14px;min-height:90px;min-width:340px;">
            For Logo
        </div>
        <div id="login_pass_form" style="border:1px solid black; height:40%;width:50%;background-color:blue;min-height:60px; min-width:300px;position:relative;float:right;bottom:-30px;">
            For Login and Password
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="video" style="border:0px solid white; height:40%;width:49.844%;background-color:indigo;position:relative;float:left;">
        <video width="450px" height="190px" controls="controls" style="position:absolute;top:30px;right:170px;">
            <source src="sampleVid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="sampleVid.ogv" type="video/ogv">
            <source src="sampleVid.webm" type="video/webm">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
    <div id="user_registration_form" style="border:0px solid white; height:74%;width:50%;background-color:purple;position:reltive;float:right;min-height:448px;">
        Registration Form
    </div>
    <div id="footer" style="border:1px solid black; height:32%;width:100%;background-color:pink;position:relative;float:right;min-height:188px;">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Setting up the dimension of the width and leaving the height dimension blank will fix this issue. It happens because If you set the two dimensions, and the actual video dimensions are not the same, it will scale to to the closest appropriate proportion using one dimension, thereby leaving blank margins at the only one dimension of the video player. The video may be centered either on the horizontal or on the vertical with blank space on either side

Comment: kindly write the for this for proper explanation

Comment: tried this but on zooming the page in or out, video size is not having the effects accordingly

Answer (score 0):

ITs your video issue as your video is not as full screen . See the following example

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html style="height:100%; width=1200px;margin:0;padding:0;">

<body style="height:100%;width=100%;margin:0;padding:0;">
<div id="container" style="background-color:#FFA500;height:100%;width:100%;position:relative;min-height:800px;min-width:1000px;" >

    <div id="logo_login_pass" style="border:1px solid black; height:25%;width:94%;background-color:white;position:relative;float:right;min-height:150px;min-width:700px;">
        <div id="logo" style="border:1px solid black; height:80%; width:30%; background-color:green; position:absolute;bottom:14px;min-height:90px;min-width:340px;">
            For Logo
        </div>
        <div id="login_pass_form" style="border:1px solid black; height:40%;width:50%;background-color:blue;min-height:60px; min-width:300px;position:relative;float:right;bottom:-30px;">
            For Login and Password
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="video" style="border:0px solid white; height:40%;width:49.844%;background-color:indigo;position:relative;float:left;">
        <video width="450px"  controls="controls" style="position:absolute;top:30px;right:170px;">
              <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
              <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm'/>


            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
    <div id="user_registration_form" style="border:0px solid white; height:74%;width:50%;background-color:purple;position:reltive;float:right;min-height:448px;">
        Registration Form
    </div>
    <div id="footer" style="border:1px solid black; height:32%;width:100%;background-color:pink;position:relative;float:right;min-height:188px;">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the element size in the video for the size you want

```
<video width="450" height="240" controls>
```

Comment: but videos can have different heights in cease of feed of videos

Answer (score 0):

Solution - Adjust Your Video Height And Width Using HTML So The Bar Fit To The Video Aspect Ratio Given By You. Then For Moving Your Video On Website Use Position Relative Property To Move Left Right Bottom Top With CSS

Answer (score 0):

Take out the width attribute and put in a max-width attribute as follows:

```
<video height="190px" controls="controls" style="position:absolute;top:30px;right:170px;max-width:450px;">
```

Before:

[image]

After:
[image]