# Html5 video tag controls longer than video being displayed

Tags: html, video

The controls are longer than my video here is my code. it's pretty simple

```
[video width="240" height="135" mp4="http://www.petersecord2014.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/PeterSecordMayoraltyKick-off-Speech23July2014.mp4"][/video]
```

Things that I have already tried from what I have read online so far :

1. added control after height (no change)
2. made height blank (no video
   because height was blank)

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335228/control-bar-wider-than-video-in-html5-css/77153513#77153513

Answer (score 0):

Try using percentages instead of px for one of your dimensions (most likely height).